# c++ :How to navigate to a particular line in a file while writing in a file?

Tags: c++, linux, file-io

The program (in c++) has to write text in a file in sequential order. But sometimes there is a need to write something on a particular line number. Is there a way to navigate to a particular line number without looping over the entire file and if there is, whats its complexity? Is there something similar to fseek?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless your file is of fixed length records, there is no fast method to locate a line.

For variable length text lines, you have to read each character to determine if it is a line ending character.  If it is, you increment the line number.

If you need to access lines by line number often, you may want to build a table of <line number, file position> records.  You would only need to perform this once.

**Edit 1:**
You could build the line position table while you are creating the file.  Before you write a text line, read and store the file position.

BTW, you can overwrite text in a file, but not insert text into the file (except appending).  To insert text, you will have to write all the original data first to a new file, write the new text, then write all the remaining text.

Comment: Assuming I know the number of lines in the file and length of each line is not the same, creating table of <line number, file position> would be the best method? If I am understanding it correctly, this will allow me to navigate to a particular line number in O(1)

Comment: He can use `seek()` and `truncate()` to avoid rewriting data before the insertion point though (for inserting text).

Answer (score 0):

The format of a typical raw text file is a sequence of bytes describing each line, then a line end marker (on some systems one byte, on others two).  Then the next line starts immediately.

The file typically ends with an end line marker.

If your file is formatted based on that, there are no fast ways to find a line, or replace it with anything except a line with the exact same number of bytes.

The advantage of this format is that there are many, many tools that can read it.

However this doesn't have to be your format.  A format where finding lines is easy, and replacing lines equally so, is quite writable.  It won't be trivial, but it isn't intractable.

For an easy approach, grab the [STXXL](http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/).  Sadly I don't see a random-access cheap-middle-insert-delete container there (like a self-balancing tree with subtree sizes stored at each node).  But maybe there is.

Answer (score -2):

You need  GotoLine() function.

For example you have file dummy.txt and you want to navigate to line 10.
So you can just do

```
fstream file("dummy.txt");
GotoLine(file, 10);
```

Answer (score -2):

```
ofstream myfile("foo.txt");
int lineNumber = 123;
for(int i=0;i<lineNumber-1;i++) myfile << "\n";
myfile << "Here I am on line number " << lineNumber << endl;
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. This does exactly what the OP requested, navigate to a particular line of a file, and write that line. This is the most efficient way of doing it.